# Google app engine: (devappserver2.py:835) No default module found.

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-module

I am trying to run a service with in google app engine. I used this command to run the local app engine development server gor Go and run the admin service.

```
goapp serve -admin_port 8081 admin
```

---

But it gives me error of "No default module found. Ignoring."

```
parminder_sohal@compact-window-137215:~/conference-central/default$ goapp serve -admin_port 8081 admin
INFO     2016-07-15 21:00:25,850 devappserver2.py:769] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2016-07-15 21:00:25,949 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://0.0.0.0:57478
INFO     2016-07-15 21:00:25,974 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "admin" running at: http://0.0.0.0:8080
INFO     2016-07-15 21:00:25,975 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://0.0.0.0:8081
WARNING  2016-07-15 21:00:25,975 devappserver2.py:835] No default module found. Ignoring.
```

Comment: isn't that just a warning? sounds reasonable warning since you ran the admin module, not the default